# Sorting objects in an array based on a property from greatest to least?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, javascript-objects

I have an array with an object in it in Javascript. I need to sort them based on a property from greatest to least.

I could not find a solution that did not use Array.sort which I am unable to use.

An example of a similar array:

```
var arr = [{"name" : "bob", "age", 45}, {"name" : "Joe", "age" : 35}, {"name" : "Amy", "age" : 20}];
```

I want to sort based on age (oldest to youngest) without array.sort.

Comment: Why exactly *without* using `.sort()`? Are you working on a homework assignment that requires that you write your own sorting function?

Comment: No this is a personal project using arrays. I am just getting an undefined error using .sort() so I am unable to use it. I was just trying to find an alternative @Pointy

Comment: @arodebaugh what exactly `undefined` error are you getting?

Comment: You need to check your setup...what you have here isn't anything. You have a variable to an array and then 2 other arrays just floating to nothing. Is this supposed to be an array with 3 objects?

Comment: @HridayModi It was saying that Array.sort() cannot return undefined and when I did a log for array.sort it returned undefined. I am using Angular + Typescript

Comment: Are you actually calling Array.sort? or are you doing arr.sort(function()... etc?

Comment: Array.sort(function (a, b) { return b.times - a.times; }); @bhmahler

Comment: You need to call sort on your array variable.  So arr.sort(function(a, b){return b.age - a.age;}). Array is a type and not an actual array so sort is not defined.  You need to sort something of the array type, not the type itself

Comment: Please show your code, the actual error message, and fix the tags if you are using Typescript rather than JS.

Comment: ES6: `arr.sort((a, b) => b.age - a.age);`

Comment: @arodebaugh `arr.sort((a,b) => b.age - a.age);` should solve your problem. It's plain javascript and should work.

Comment: Thanks for your help found my solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering arr an array of objects, you can sort you arr by passing any property.

Try the following:

```js
var arr = [{"name" : "bob", "age": 45}, {"name" : "Joe", "age" : 35}, {"name" : "Amy", "age" : 20}];

function sortArray(arr,prop){
  arr.sort((a,b)=>{
    if(typeof a[prop] ==='string')
      return b[prop].localeCompare(a[prop]);
    return b[prop] - a[prop];
  });
}

//Sort array based on name
sortArray(arr,"name");
console.log(arr);

//Sort array based on age
sortArray(arr,"age");
console.log(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use `sort`, you can implement sorting the old way, via `for` loops. For example, here is an [**insertion sort**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort) in descending order (from biggest to smallest):

```js
var arr = [{"name" : "Joe", "age" : 35}, {"name" : "Amy", "age" : 20}, {"name" : "bob", "age" : 45}];

function insertionSort (items) {
  var len = items.length;
  for (var i = 1; i < len; i++) {
    var tmp = items[i]; 
    for (var j = i - 1; j >= 0 && (items[j]['age'] > tmp['age']); j--) {
      items[j + 1] = items[j];
    }
    items[j + 1] = tmp;
  }
  arr = arr.reverse();
}

insertionSort(arr);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks I will try this now

Comment: It's working but it is not keeping name... Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: Sorry, posted example with some issues, I'm fixing now